# PostgreSQL connector with PHP on windows platform

Tags: php, postgresql

I am making an editor. I need to connect my php code to postgresql.
This uses command like this

`$dbconnect = pg_connect()`;

but my compiler is unable to detect `pg_connect`;

So i need connector to connect this.
I am using `Windows Platform`

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

check for `extension=php_pgsql.dll` string in `php.ini` to be uncommented

Comment: Please Give me link /guide for step by step to add extension for php

Comment: if youre on windows i guess this extensrion is included already: look in `php/ext` dir. than uncomment that string and restart apache.

Comment: I Agree. But My problem is i am using phelanger which is integrated product with .net and am compiling my program under .net environment.I could not find my php/ext file

Comment: so for this i cant help you (don't know even what `phelanger` is). edit the question: it's where unclear and  there's nothing about `.net`

Comment: I Got my my php_pgsql.dll in C:\Program Files\Phalanger 3.0\Extensions\ but to inlcude.what i need to write because it is not automatically detected in my php code

Answer (score 0):

Look at PDO 
http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-pgsql.php

Here is an example how to connect to PostgreSQL:
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#4.1